# How to connect to different classes in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Id like to ask how to connect 2 different classes. I have the following codes in 2 classes (2 classes because i have created 2 different interface. 1 is the QMainwindow and the other 1 is QWidget).

Here's the code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def open_inv_search_form(self):
            self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.ui = Ui_Inv_Search()
            self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
            self.window.show()
            MainWindow.setEnabled(False)


class Inv_Search(QWidget, Ui_Inv_Search):    
    def __init__(self,):
            super(Inv_Search, self).__init__()

            self.btn_close_search.clicked.connect(self.close_inv_search_form)

    def close_inv_search_form(self):
            Inv_Search.hide()
            MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
```

The idea is when SEARCH button is clicked in MainWindow, Inv_Search will pop up while MainWindow will be disabled. I have done this part correctly. When CLOSE button is clicked, Inv_Search will be hide and MainWindow will be enabled. However, when CLOSE button is clicked, nothing happened. And there is no error at all.

**UPDATE**

I was able to successfully do what I wanted. Here's the changes I did. Let me know if this is fine or can be better. Nevertheless, this code works.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        Inv_Search.show()          #called to connect to the new window. This is the key since what i previously did only call the ui, but not connect it to the class itself. 
        MainWindow.setEnabled(False)

class Inv_Search(QWidget, Ui_Inv_Search):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(Inv_Search, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.btn_close_search.clicked.connect(self.close_inv_search_form)

    def close_inv_search_form(self):    

        Inv_Search.close()  # I cant figure out how can I use the self but this works fine
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    Inv_Search = Inv_Search() #added this one
    #ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    #ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You should definitely use other names for instances of classes than the class name itself. I refer to `MainWindow = MainWindow()`. Here you do something very weird. In the current namespace you overwrite the definition of the class with an instance of this class. Better do something like `main = MainWindow()`.

Comment: When you place the method call of `show()` right under the headline of the class definition you attach a static attribute without name assigning the return value of `show()`. This also leads to weird behaviour. Better: Put the call `invsearch.show()` (instance not singleton) in the constructor of `MainWindow` and make sure the instance `invsearch` of class `Inv_Search` is created globally _before_ `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that there is more code and a .ui file somewhere. It looks like this line

```
Inv_Search.hide()
```

should be changed to

```
self.hide()
```

Also, I think that because you need to call the method on the instance, not the class.

```
self.ui = Ui_Inv_Search()
```

should probably be

```
self.ui = Inv_Search()
```

You are doing a similar thing with `MainWindow`. It's a little more difficult here, because you will need to have an instance of `MainWindow` stored somewhere accessible. Although you may be able to access the `MainWindow` instance through [`QtWidget.parentWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#parentWidget), in Python I prefer to just pass the instance to the constructor. So

```
def __init__(self, mainWindow):
    self.mainWindow = mainWindow
    # ... all the other stuff too
```

as your `Inv_Search` constructor, and

```
self.ui = Inv_Search(self)
    # notice the new ^ argument
```

in your `MainWindow` constructor. And then

```
self.mainWindow.setEnabled(True)
```

in your class method. Also, your argument signature is wrong for the `clicked` signal. Use

```
def close_inv_search_form(self, checked=None):
                    # Need this ^ argument, even if you don't use it.
```

In reality, it seems like the functionality you are trying to accomplish is best suited for a modal dialog, such as that provided by [`QDialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html), which will natively handle many of the effect I think you are looking for.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. I'm confused because all my buttons in Class MainWindow worked except for this one which is in a new class. My theory is the button when clicked dont send signal to the application that it has to do something. I just did the same with all other buttons but this one, dont just work. hmm.

Comment: I've edited my answer to point out a couple of other suspected issues.

Comment: still dont work. I tried to transfer the class to a separate file and run it. The button still dont work.

Comment: Hi buck, I updated the question with an answer. Look at the bottom part. It works to me. Any comment?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Inv_Search.hide()` and `MainWindow.setEnabled(True)` in `close_inv_search_form`, you call the methods on the class itself not on the instance, which is what you actually have to.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import qApp

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def open_inv_search_form(self):
            self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.window.ui = Ui_Inv_Search()      # You have to set the attributes of the
            self.window.ui.setupUi(self.window)   # "window" not the instance of MainWindow
            self.window.show()
            self.setEnabled(False)

class Inv_Search(QWidget, Ui_Inv_Search):    
    def __init__(self,):
            super(Inv_Search, self).__init__()

            self.btn_close_search.clicked.connect(self.close_inv_search_form)

    def close_inv_search_form(self):
            self.hide()             # Use the method "hide" on the instance
            qApp.setEnabled(True)   # Use the method "setEnabled" on the instance

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = QApplication()
    main = MainWindow()   # This is the instance that can be referred to by qApp
    main.exec_()
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried it but nothing still happens.

Comment: Did you try the method `self.close()`?

Comment: I did. It seems like the window is just there to show the form but dont do anything. The close button dont work even if I tried to just show a QMessageBox. Seems like click button is getting no signal at all that its being clicked. This is part I get confused because all my other buttons from MainWindow works perfectly fine.

Comment: @AnthonyGaupo What is the "close button"? Do you mean `Inv_Search.btn_close_search`? Did you try debugging it - `print` something within `close_inv_search_form`...

Comment: the name of the button is btn_close_search it is under the class Inv_Search (I used a different class from Class MainWindow because i created these 2 windows  separately in QT)

Comment: Have a look at my changes.

Comment: Hi @sven, I updated the question with an answer. Look at the bottom part. It works to me. Any comment?